# Replicated Latin Square Analysis in R Language with ANOVA

Tags: r, latin-square

I am executing a 1 factor(tool) experiment with 2 treatments and 2 block variables (participant and process). In other words, a 2x2 Latin square.

One of the block variables is the participants. As my sample has 8 participants, I have 4 2x2 latin squares.

To do the analysis of just 1 Latin square, I am using ANOVA through the following commands in R:

```
result = aov(time~participant+process+tool);
print(summary(result));
```

My questions is: **How can I execute an ANOVA test with replicated latin squares in R?**

Comment: Look at the packages `lme4` and `nlme`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a good reference to understand how to analyse replicated latin squares in:

http://halweb.uc3m.es/esp/Personal/personas/jmmarin/esp/Disenno/CursoDisExpSAS.pdf

In page 42 is possible to observe that my case is: **"new rows and same columns"**

So, the ANOVA table should be according to the table in page 46. Special attention to the sources and degree of freedom (df).

To code the expressed concepts in R, I did the following:

result = aov(time~tool+**participant:replic**+process+**replic**);

The bold part is the changes in order to represent the table presented in page 46.

Comment: Strictly speaking, this is ok, but I consider the latin square a special case of a randomization with repeats, and I am not interested in the column. So I prefer to put the replications into the repeats (see below).

Answer (score 2):

```
library(nlme) # Avoid lme4 for starter, documentation is not that good yet
result = lme(time~process*tool, data=...., random = ~1|participant)
summary(result)
```